# How to find variance for given problem?

Tags: statistics, expected-value, variance

Suppose the expected earnings for a farm depends on the number of worms per apple. The number of worms per apple has a Poisson distribution with mean 0.32.

a) The expected earnings per apple depends on number of defects: `13-5X`. What is the expected earning for 10 apples?
answer: I have done this part, where I do  `10 * (13-5*0.32)` which is the right answer.

b) Find the variance of earnings for 10 apples.

This is where I'm stuck. Thanks for any help

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know how to calculate the variance for 2 apple?

Comment: I know the formula is V(u) = E(b) where b = (u - E(u))^2. But this gives me a very large number

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- If $X$ has variance $\sigma^2$ and $Y=aX+b$ then $Y$ has variance $a^2 \sigma^2$
- The variance of the sum of independent random variables
  is equal to the sum of their variances
- The variance of a Poisson distribution is equal to its mean